# Python to Json conversion

Tags: python, json

I have a script which is converting an excel to json and have this code.

```
l3 = dict( zip(l1.split(','), l2.split(',')) )
print l3
```

where l1 and l2 are lists.

the output is something like this

```
{'brand': 'car', 'color': 'red', 'model': '2009', 'value': '100000'}
```

Is it possible to remove the single quotes for those keys.

Comment: Then you'd be making them variables and it would return a `NameError`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to create a JSON-compatible string from a Python object:

```
>>> import json
>>> l3 = {'brand': 'car', 'color': 'red', 'model': '2009', 'value': '100000'}
>>> json.dumps(l3)
'{"model": "2009", "color": "red", "value": "100000", "brand": "car"}'
```

(or create a JSON file directly):

```
>>> with open("test.json", "w") as j: json.dump(l3, j)
```

Comment: I do not want quotes for keys.Can i get like this {model: "2009", color: "red", value: "100000", brand: "car"}

Comment: @user2957389: But then it's not JSON anymore, and why would you want a variable as a key? Keys need to be immutable, and while there are immutable "variables" in Python, it's almost always a bad idea to use them that way. Read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

As noted, this won't be a valid json. But if you insist, it can be done for example with some custom class:

```
class NoQuoteReprString(str):
     def __repr__(self):
         return str(self)
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = {'brand': 'car', 'color': 'red', 'model': '2009', 'value': '100000'}
>>> no_quote_data = {NoQuoteReprString(k): v for k, v in data.items()}
>>> repr(no_quote_data)
"{color: 'red', brand: 'car', model: '2009', value: '100000'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is easy to remove the quotes from the string, I don't think you should do that since JSON keys should have double quotes around them.

I think you should be doing JSON conversion [using `json.dump` or `json.dumps`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html) depending on your requirements.